# How do persistence work in nHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, orm

How does nHibernate or any ORM cache data? Where does it store data?
I have used custom functions with sqldatareaders calling stored procedures so far. So I'm not able to visualize how ORM thing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NHibernate has multiple levels of how it caches data but the simplest form (1st level cache) stores database objects read in the "Session" object which internally it's basically an in memory hash table with the primary key as it's hash key.